# I need help binding text to a line positioned between two circles, and then having the distance of the line updated every time the circles are moved

Tags: java, javafx

I have 2 circles with a line bound to there x and y's the circles can be moved by dragging and the line will move with them. I don't know how to position the text so it is at the center of the line and moves when the circles are moved. I also can't figure out how to update the text to the distance between the 2 circles every time they move.

```
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextAlignment;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CircleWithStirngApp extends Application {
   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Circle circle1 = new Circle(40,40,10);
        Circle circle2 = new Circle(120,150,10);
        Line line = new Line();
        Text text = new Text(60,60,"");

        line.startXProperty().bind(circle1.centerXProperty());
        line.startYProperty().bind(circle1.centerYProperty());
        line.endXProperty().bind(circle2.centerXProperty());
        line.endYProperty().bind(circle2.centerYProperty());

        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.getChildren().add(circle1);
        pane.getChildren().add(circle2);
        pane.getChildren().add(line);
        pane.getChildren().add(text);

        circle1.setOnMouseDragged(e ->{
            circle1.setCenterX(e.getX());
            circle1.setCenterY(e.getY());
        });
        circle2.setOnMouseDragged(e ->{
            circle2.setCenterX(e.getX());
            circle2.setCenterY(e.getY());
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane,200,200);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Circle With String");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }
}
```

Comment: This is a [duplicate of a question asked on JavaRanch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/662710/JavaFX/java/Making-streets-JavaFX-cool-rhyme).

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
DoubleBinding distance = Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
    Point2D start = new Point2D(circle1.getCenterX(), circle1.getCenterY());
    Point2D end = new Point2D(circle2.getCenterX(), circle2.getCenterY());
    return start.distance(end);
}, circle1.centerXProperty(), circle1.centerYProperty(), 
   circle2.centerXProperty(), circle2.centerYProperty());
```

and then you can do things like

```
text.textProperty().bind(distance.asString("Distance: %f"));
```

For centering the text you can use

```
text.xProperty().bind(circle1.centerXProperty().add(circle2.centerXProperty()).divide(2));
text.yProperty().bind(circle1.centerYProperty().add(circle2.centerYProperty()).divide(2));
```

Comment: Thanks to @fabian for the edit.

Comment: Thanks to @James_D for the help.

Comment: Thanks to @fabian for the help.